# SHA256 is not generating right hash in php

Tags: php, string, sha256

Following is the procedure for generating a sha256 based hashed.

**Generated Hash**

The hash query string parameter is to be followed by the generated hash for that specific request. To generate the hash:

1. Take the body of the HTTP POST request
2. Add the provided API Secret to the end of the body
3. Converts it to SHA256 and converts the hashed message to hexadecimal format

For example, assuming the provided API Secret is "secretapikey" and the HTTP POST body contains the following:

`{ "apiKey": 123, "invoiceId": 1 }`

The generated hash will be:

`d48cf8a852713844603d7c8cbefb3e81cfb29e7540d98f06affdf58322c1038e`

Below is the steps taken to produce the above generated hash:

HTTP POST Body =>   `{ "apiKey": 123, "invoiceId": 1 }`

Secret  => secretapikey

Text to be hashed   => `{ "apiKey": 123, "invoiceId": 1 }secretapikey`

SHA-256 Hash    => `d48cf8a852713844603d7c8cbefb3e81cfb29e7540d98f06affdf58322c1038e`

I have to concatinate two strings (`{ "apiKey": 123, "invoiceId": 1 }secretapikey`) and then hash them to send to an api end point. But the Hash generated by following code is not according to hash generated by an online sha256:-

```
$secretapikey = "secretapikey";
$postbody = array();
$postbody['apiKey'] = "123";
$postbody['invoiceId'] = 1;

$jpb = json_encode($postbody);

$hashed = $jpb.$secretapikey; //Here is Problem. It is not concatenated according to requirement


$result = hash('SHA256', $hashed);

echo $result;
```

This is the value of `$result`

```
d2c5d184be42ff4ae3a0046d0727c026f38c1e92f8960cb9d17d496c7b89b7b3
```

whereas it should be

```
d48cf8a852713844603d7c8cbefb3e81cfb29e7540d98f06affdf58322c1038e
```

Comment: `123` is a number - `"123"` is a string. json_encoding them results in different strings. i'm pretty sure that's your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`hash('SHA256', $hashed);` is doing its job right

and `$hashed = $jpb.$secretapikey;` is joining the two strings correctly.

The reason you don't get the hash you expect is that the JSON you use for the test is

`{ "apiKey": 123, "invoiceId": 1 }`

while the JSON produced by `json_encode($postbody);`

is `{"apiKey":123,"invoiceId":1}`

**without** spaces.